# draggable component in react not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-position, draggable

I am trying to make a draggable button using react.

The button drags over the page in a proper manner but when I drop it. Its top and left values become negative(not even reset to their original top:0,left:0) i.e. the component goes out of the page.

code sand box link : [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/34v6g)

main draggable.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

class DraggableButton extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            dragging: false,
            diffX: 0,
            diffY: 0,
            style: {
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }
        }
    }

    handleMouseDown = (event) => {
        console.log("element caught");
        this.setState({
            diffX: event.clientX - event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().left,
            diffY: event.clientY - event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().top,
            dragging: true
        })
    }

    handleMouseMove = (event) => {
        if (this.state.dragging) {
            console.log("dragging");
            let left = event.clientX - this.state.diffX;
            let top = event.clientY - this.state.diffY;

            this.setState({
                style: {
                    left,
                    top
                }
            }, console.log("style ", this.state.style))
        }
    }


    handleMouseUp = () => {

        console.log('element released');
        console.log('left value ', this.state.style.left);
        console.log('top value ', this.state.style.top);
        this.setState({
            dragging: false,
        })
    }


    render() {
        return (

            <Button
                variant="contained" color="primary"
                style={{ position: "absolute", ...this.state.style }}
                draggable={true}
                onDragStart={this.handleMouseDown}
                onDrag={this.handleMouseMove}
                onDragEnd={this.handleMouseUp}
            // onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
            // onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}
            // onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp}
            >
                draggable button
            </Button>
        );
    }
}

export default DraggableButton;
```

console screenshot :

[image: console view]

As is visible in the image above at the time of dragging top: 193  left : 309 and as we dropped the element it turned to left: -109 top: -13.

why is this happening how can we fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `handleMouseMove` you need to check if `event.clientX` is a positive integer and then change the state, or else it will reduce the `diffX` value and it will be nevative. (On drag release this becomes 0)

```
let left = event.clientX - this.state.diffX;



  handleMouseMove = (event) => {
    if (this.state.dragging) {
      let left = event.clientX - this.state.diffX;
      let top = event.clientY - this.state.diffY;

      if (event.clientX !== 0)
        this.setState({
          style: {
            left,
            top
          }
        });
    }
  };
```

Comment: this worked can you tell me why onDrag ( handleMouseMove ) was fired when it should be just onDragEnd ( handleMouseUp ) when we release the mouse button

Comment: since you are in dragging process, it will be always called. check this `https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_ondrag` and replace "The p element is being dragged" with `new Date().getTime()` to see that it is constantly updating the div